# Migrate files from S3 to Azure Files via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-files

I am trying to migrate files from S3 to Azure Files.  I have successfully created S3 as the Source and can select my Buckets.  When I try and configure Azure File Storage I get this error

```
[{"code":9005,"message":"Error occurred when trying to access the file in Folder '\\\\<storage url>.file.core.windows.net\\archive', File filter: ''."}]
```

Under the "Edit Linked Service (File System)" I am using the default integration runtime, the Host is pulled straight from storagename - Files > archive - Properties > URL, and the credentials I am using for testing are Global Admins.